# Process flows not showing up in environment

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow, metadata, process

I'm trying to push process flows that I created in my dev env and am trying to push it onto my test environment.

I updated my `package.xml` file to retrieve `flow` metadata and then uploaded it to `workbench`. From there I was able to get all the necessary flows I require. When I deploy my code, the deployment is a success but I can't see any `processes` when I go through `setup -> process builder`.

Comment: How are you trying to push it - sfdx CLI, ANT, change set, 3rd party tool? Are these developer edition orgs, Sandboxes, or scratch orgs? When you say you've "grabbed the metadata" -- how? Have you looked at what you "grabbbed" to see if reasonable-looking XML is there? Are you getting any error messages? Your question is unanswerably vague and lacking useful detail - please edit to provide more context. Read or review [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for guidance.

Comment: If using V44 or later, you don't use `flowDefinition`. The metadata API only needs `flow` and will use the most recent version

Comment: Still is not being deployed in the environment :( (only used `flow` metadata)